Coefficients of polynomials vs trigonometric product
Let's consider the family of sequences of coefficients in the expansion
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{3^i}+x^{3^{i+1}})=\sum_{k\geq0}a_n(k)\, x^k.$$
Remark. Evidently, the RHS is a finite sum.
Here is a numerical coincidence for which I ask a direct connection as to why?

QUESTION. It is possible to offer say a recurrence for both sides as to why it is so but is there a more direct connection between the two sides?
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(4+2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}\right)\right)
=\sum_{k\geq0}a_n(k)^2.$$


I guess the first product should start at $i=0$?

https://oeis.org/A001835

@HjalmarRosengren: Thank you, edited now.

Nemo's comment, less tersely stated, is that the trigonometric product is the number of domino tilings of a $3\times 2n$ rectangle.
